# Customizing the checkout form

Tags: 8, forms, commerce

I need to fill Billing Info form with data that the user has filled in another page of my commerce site.

I've made a hook_form_alter with the following weird code (with the help of kint):

```
function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
   switch ($form_id) {
    case 'commerce_checkout_flow_multistep_default':
      $form["payment_information"]["add_payment_method"]["billing_information"]["address"]["widget"][0]["address"]["#default_value"]["given_name"]="NAME";
      $form["payment_information"]["add_payment_method"]["billing_information"]["address"]["widget"][0]["address"]["#default_value"]["country_code"]="IT";
```

It works with name but it does not select the country code; i would also like to hide some fields (like address2) ... is there a way to unset() or hide() a field? If i try to hide($form[....]) it does not hide it because it only contains the item value. I have not found a way, indeed, to modify/insert fields for this form.

I know i can do it via CSS, but i would prefer to do it in form_alter.